# Who exactly is the antichrist, and what is his power?

Tags: prophet-isa, dajjal

I'm just curious, I read a little bit and it made me want to ask this question. Who exactly is the antichrist, and what is his power?

Answer (score 1):

the Anti-Christ/Dajjal (one who conceals the truth or deceives) will appear. 
o   He will rule for 40 days, but the 1st of days will equal to 1 year, then another 1 month and the rest as regular days. 
o   He will be one-eyed (like a protruding grape) and Kafir (letters K.F.R) will be written on his forehead. 
o   Madinah would rock 3 times on his appearance and destroyed during WWIII
o   He would kill a pious man and then bring him back to life
o   He would appear from the east
o   He will take over the world by coercion, by controlling business and politics. 
o   He will be a charismatic leader, red in complexion, and curly hair
o   He will be Jewish (or atheist) and his army will include many Jews from Israel
o   He will display anger in speeches to public (like Hitler)
o   At 1st he will appear as a tyrannical king, and then claim to be a prophet, then lord. 
o   He will conquer country after country except Makkah/Madinah.

Answer (score 0):

Antichrist is not Islamic definition. It comes from bible. However, you can understand Dajjal as Antichrist. Subject of those two character is same: Claim to be messiah.
You can look further information on this wiki page: [Masih ad-Dajjal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masih_ad-Dajjal)